# How to copy table to another table?

Tags: sql-server, copy, identity

I have a table with 1 000 000 records:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[x2](
    [session_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [node_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_x2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
));
```

I need to replace the field

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)
```

with

```
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1)
```

But all data (including id values) should be copied to the new table and id should be IDENTITY but bigint.

I have created the new table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[x2_new](
    [session_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [node_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_x2_new] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
));
```

and tried to copy data:

```
insert into x2_new(session_id,node_id,id)
select session_id,node_id,id from x2;
```

But it is slow. How to copy data to the new table faster?

Comment: Define slow? Inserting a million records on a table which is indexed isn't going to be as fast as one that isn't indexed, of course

Comment: yes, but on  other side this query select into t1 from t is faster than insert into () select ... from. But I cannot use it because of identity field

Comment: Well a faster way would be to drop the constraints and indexes and simply alter the table column type.

Comment: You could still use select into...you should be explicitly naming your columns anyway so all you need to do is add a convert to the id column. convert(bigint, id) I would also ask why you need to make an entirely new copy of 1,000,000 + rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case.. you need to do an 'identity_insert OFF' on your destination and insert with your script.. try setting NoLock too.. but is this a one time activity or a repetitive one?

Answer (score 0):

If both your tables are in same databse, why don't you use Import Data Task feature , select the columns and run the SSIS package immediately..

Comment: At least because finally I need a script which will be provided to clients which use my database. You see: I am trying to solve the problem int identity overflow, to replace int  identity->bigint identity

Comment: In that case.. you need to do an &#39;identity_insert OFF&#39; on your destination and insert with your script.. try setting NoLock too and of course, cast int to bigint.. but is this a one time activity or a repetitive one?

Comment: Yes, it is one time operation. The reason is: the identity  INT is not enough, need to convert to identity BIGINT. That is why I test this operation on my db and then will provide the script to clients.